# intuition behind the process of finding Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, laurent-series

So I learned in my complex analysis class the concept of Laurent series but my teacher's approach was fully theoretical: no actual example and no example on how to find a Laurent series for a function on a specific annulus.

So when I started doing some exercises I obviously found it very difficult and frustration because I have no idea how to proper tackle the problem.

My first exercise is the following:

> Find the Laurent series of the functions:
>   $$f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^2}\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ g(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}$$
>   on the annulus $0 < |z| < 3$ and $|z| > 3$

Knowing the theory behind Laurent series, my first thought, was to apply the formula:

$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$

I think this may be possible for function $g$ but I don't see it working that easily for function $f$.

So my question is: What is the most appropriate way to find the Laurent series of this functions? What are the basic things you look for in a function in other to make the process of finding a Laurent series more easy. How does the different annulus chance you approach for solving the problem?

Basically I am asking you to teach me some tips and teach me the mindset behind finding Laurent series and the intuition that my teacher should have have in his lecture.

Comment: for $f(z),$ if you know the Taylor series for $\sin(z)$, you could divide each term by $z^2$; for $g(z)$, you could apply that $\dfrac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ when $|x|<1$

Comment: Can we still use a Taylor series if the function domain is an annulus?

Comment: Because for the Taylor series we have that the coefficients are: $c_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$. And $z - a$ will not be defined because $a$ is a singularity